# DomPDF content table not rendering correctly

Tags: php, dompdf

I'm having an issue with DomPDF Content table generation. The generated HTML is a bit longer, and can have tens on chapters which needs to be displayed in the content table at the beginning (using $GLOBAL and DomPDF objects with replacement of some Page ID's). The exact issue is that the first page of the content table is rendered perfectly, after this it %%CH[PageID]%% doesn't get replaced.

This part of the code has the issue:

```
<script type="text/php">
$GLOBALS['chapters'] = array();
$GLOBALS["contentStartsAt"] = false;
$GLOBALS['backside'] = $pdf->open_object();</script>
<h5 style="margin: 20px 0; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;">Deel Lorem ipsum title</h5>
1.Lorem ipsum title%%CH190%%
1.1.Lorem ipsum title%%CH303%%
1.2.Lorem ipsum title%%CH304%%
1.3.Lorem ipsum title%%CH305%%
1.4.Lorem ipsum title%%CH306%%
1.5.Lorem ipsum title%%CH307%%
1.6.Lorem ipsum title%%CH308%%
1.7.Lorem ipsum title%%CH309%%
1.7.1.Lorem ipsum title%%CH315%%
1.7.2.Lorem ipsum title%%CH316%%
1.7.3.Lorem ipsum title%%CH317%%
1.8.Lorem ipsum title%%CH310%%
1.9.Lorem ipsum title%%CH311%%
1.10.Lorem ipsum title%%CH312%%
1.11.Lorem ipsum title%%CH313%%
1.12.Lorem ipsum title%%CH314%%
2.Lorem ipsum title%%CH191%%
2.1.Lorem ipsum title%%CH318%%
2.2.Lorem ipsum title%%CH319%%
2.2.1.Lorem ipsum title%%CH329%%
2.2.2.Lorem ipsum title%%CH330%%
<script type="text/php">
$pdf->close_object();
</script>
......
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NEGLLg

[DomPDF Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kROYY.png)

Attached you will find a screenshot about the issue, and the source HTML file.
Any advice is appreciated. Thanks!